# How to retrieve an array from a hash that has been passed to a subroutine in perl

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am trying to write a subroutine that takes in a hash of arrays as an argument. However, when I try to retrieve one of the arrays, I seem to get the size of the array instead of the array itself.

```
my(%hash) = (  );
$hash{"aaa"} = ["blue", 1];

_subfoo("test", %hash);

sub _subfoo {

    my($test ,%aa) = @_;

    foreach my $name (keys %aa) {
        my @array = @{$aa{$name}};
        print $name. " is ". @array ."\n";
    }
}
```

This returns 2 instead of (blue, 1) as I expected. Is there some other way to handle arrays in hashes when in a subroutine?

Apologies if this is too simple for stack overflow, first time poster, and new to programming.

Comment: The indentation in your code is very messy. You should use a proper text editor with auto-indent, such as vim.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're putting your `@array` array into a scalar context right here:

```
print $name. " is ". @array ."\n";
```

An array in scalar context gives you the number of elements in the array and `@array` happens to have 2 elements. Try one of these instead:

```
print $name . " is " . join(', ', @array) . "\n";
print $name, " is ", @array, "\n";
print "$name is @array\n";
```

and you'll see the elements of your `@array`. Using [`join`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/join.html) lets you paste the elements together as you please; the second one evaluates `@array` in list context and will mash the values together without separating them; the third interpolates `@array` by joining its elements together with [`$"`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24LIST_SEPARATOR) (which is a single space by default).

Comment: +1. You can also write `print "$name is @array\n"`, which will implicitly join the elements of `@array` by the current value of `$"` (which defaults to `' '`).

Comment: @ruakh: Yeah, thanks. I was adding that option (and the perldoc.perl.org links) while your comment came in.

Comment: Thank you so much, I would never have thought of that.

Answer (score 4):

As mu is too short has mentioned, you used the array in scalar context, and therefore it returned its length instead of its elements. I had some other pointers about your code.

Passing arguments by reference is sometimes a good idea when some of those arguments are arrays or hashes. The reason for this is that arrays and hashes are expanded into lists before being passed to the subroutine, which makes something like this impossible:

```
foo(@bar, @baz);
sub foo {                        # This will not work
    my (@array1, @array2) = @_;  # All the arguments will end up in @array1
    ...
}
```

This will work, however:

```
foo(\@bar, \@baz);
sub foo {                  
    my ($aref1, $aref2) = @_;
    ...
}
```

You may find that in your case, [`each`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/each.html) is a nice function for your purposes, as it will make dereferencing the array a bit neater.

```
foo("test", \%hash);  # note the backslash to pass by reference

sub foo {
    my ($test, $aa) = @_; # note use of scalar $aa to store the reference

    while (my ($key, $value) = each %$aa)) {  # note dereferencing of $aa
        print "$key is @$value\n";            # ...and $value
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, again this is so good. Thank you for your help. I don't have the rep to plus 1 unfortunately.

Comment: +1 and a comment on your first example: In principle it's possible with prototypes, but should be avoided unless absolutely necessary: `sub foo(\@\@);foo(@bar, @baz);sub foo(\@\@) {my @array1 = @{shift()};my @array2 = @{shift()};}`